# Attempt to get an attribute always results in a null

Tags: c#, attributes, null

first question on here but a heavy stackflow user/lover.

I'm having a problem with an attribute always being null.  The following shows how the attribute is used:

```
    [Format("d")]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; private set; }
```

The attribute definition is as follows:

```
    using System;

    namespace XXX.Aspnet.Binding
    {
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
        public class FormatAttribute : Attribute
        {
            #region Properties

            public string Format { get; set; }

            #endregion

            #region Constructors

            public FormatAttribute(string format)
            {
                Format = format;
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

I've written an extension method as the code for getting attributes if a bit ugly.  Its as follows:

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace XXX.Aspnet.Binding.Extensions
    {
        internal static class GetCustomAttributeExtension
        {
            #region GetCustomAttribute

            public static TAttribute GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(this PropertyInfo                 propertyInfo, bool inherit = false)
            {
                return propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherit).Cast<TAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();              
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Finally the call to retrieve the attribute is as follows:

```
    var formatAttribute = pi.GetCustomAttribute<FormatAttribute>();
```

Can anybody suggest why this would not work?  I've also tried doing it the traditional way without the extension method.

**Edited**

To make setter private as per Sebi's suggestion on the of chance we get this solved and someone else finds the code useful

Comment: Are you applying the attribute in a partial class via `MetadataType`?

Comment: Iam not sure but in my opinion you have to declare the Property Attribute with your class name and constructor!?. You are typing Format("d") why dont FormatAttribute("d"). In this case you can make setter private.

Comment: Bill its not a MetadataType class as per MVC, its nasty old WebForms.

Comment: Sebi I'd tried using the full FormatAttribute name but hadn't thought of using a private setter.  Good call!  Don't think its going to make a difference to the null issue though.

Comment: How is `pi` obtained?

Comment: There is no difference between `[Format("d")]` and `[FormatAttribute("d")]`. The compiler will add `Attribute` to the name if it cannot find an attribute class named `Format`, and thus the two will compile to the same code.

Comment: Hi Lasse.  Yip was aware of the no need for the Attribute suffix but good for others to know if they read this.

Comment: With regards to how pi is obtained (I didn't write this portion, I'd have called it propertyInfo to be clearer as to what it is, bit OCD about that).  'var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
'  Its then enumerated.  Again this portion of the code is not mine.  I hadn't though to look further up the process.

Comment: What .NET framework are you using? If 4 or higher there's an existing BCL extension method almost identical to yours [CustomAttributeExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am using 4 and wasn't aware of the BCL extension method.  I've give the built-in version a try.  Thank you @Richard. (just checked and its 4.5 only, we don't yet have permission to upgrade either .NET to 4.5 or WebForms to 4.5 yet which is a real pain)

Comment: Thank you every body for your help.  Turns out the other developer's pi was not related to the property being enumerated.  Think I'll take the blame on this one but your help has definitely assisted.